Angular SSR WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory
I have my Angular 17 website running on server, and on every call i get this error in log file
1|server  | ERROR Or {enter code here1|server  |   headers: t {
1|server  |     normalizedNames: Map(0) {},
1|server  |     lazyUpdate: null,
1|server  |     headers: Map(0) {}
1|server  |   },
1|server  |   status: 0,
1|server  |   statusText: 'Unknown Error',
1|server  |   url: 'https://www.backend.url.com/article/123id456',
1|server  |   ok: false,
1|server  |   name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
1|server  |   message: 'Http failure response for https://www.backend.url.com/article/123id456: 0 undefined',
1|server  |   error: TypeError: fetch failed
1|server  |       at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11) {
1|server  |     cause: RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: Cannot allocate Wasm memory for new instance
1|server  |         at lazyllhttp (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7806:32)
1|server  |   }
1|server  | }

I tried to search the internet, update undici, see how WebAssembly works, went back to ssr configuration step by step, now I ran out of ideas
